# Migrate fails on warning "'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release'

Tags: mysql, django, migrate

In my Django project I am trying to change a database field from OneToOne to ForeignKey. When I run 'python manage.py migrate', it breaks with a long traceback ending with the warning I quoted in the title. I know others have hit this problem, but I can't find a solution that gets me around it.

I have added the following to my local_settings.py DATABASES:

```
'OPTIONS': {
            'autocommit': True,
            'charset': 'utf8mb4',  
           }
```

At first I tried simply changing OneToOne to ForeignKey but hit this problem. So I decided to do it in discrete steps by first deleting the field and later adding it with the new field type. But I can't even delete the field.

Here is the migrations file that is produced by makemigrations and is the one that migrate breaks on:

```
# Generated by Django 2.2.3 on 2019-07-18 09:59

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('sweaters', '0011_auto_20190718_0954'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='sweater',
            name='yarn_for',
        ),
    ]
```

Here is the full traceback I get:

```
$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: account, admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions, sweaters
Running migrations:
  Applying sweaters.0012_remove_sweater_yarn_for...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 897, in fetchall
    self._handle_eof(eof)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 838, in _handle_eof
    self._warnings[0][1], self._warnings[0][2])
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 3719: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 178, in database_forwards
    schema_editor.remove_field(from_model, from_model._meta.get_field(self.name))
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 479, in remove_field
    fk_names = self._constraint_names(model, [field.column], foreign_key=True)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 1115, in _constraint_names
    constraints = self.connection.introspection.get_constraints(cursor, model._meta.db_table)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/django/introspection.py", line 320, in get_constraints
    for constraint, column, ref_table, ref_column in cursor.fetchall():
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 96, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 897, in fetchall
    self._handle_eof(eof)
  File "/Users/frankjernigan/Documents/webdev/phrancko-web-dev/phrancko.com/phrancko-project/myenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 838, in _handle_eof
    self._warnings[0][1], self._warnings[0][2])
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: (3719, "3719: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.", None)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with MySQL switching it's default, and `mysql-connector-python` not being up to date. A work around is provided here:

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29678

What version of `mysql-connector-python` are you using? I'm wondering if it might have been patched in a more recent version with the work-around in the link.

Comment: I'm using version 8.0.12. I'll try upgrading to 8.0.16 and let you know it that works.

Comment: No, it did not fix the problem